# php pdo where clauses

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, where-clause

I am trying to add more than one where clause to the statement but was unable to do so. the 3rd line from last i want to add 2 more conditions, how to do that? where isdone = -1 and name = "something"

here is what i tried:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=timeclock", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                $res = $conn->query("SELECT oracleid
                     , name 
                     , des 
                     , clockingindate
                     , clockingoutdate  
                     , timediff(clockingoutdate, clockingindate) as duration
                     , total
                FROM attendance_records
                     JOIN (
                            SELECT oracleid
                                 , sec_to_time(sum(timestampdiff(SECOND, clockingindate, clockingoutdate))) as total
                            FROM attendance_records
                            where isdone =-1
                            GROUP BY oracleid
                          ) tots USING (oracleid)
                          where isdone =-1
                ORDER BY oracleid, clockingindate
                ");
```

Comment: `where isdone =-1 and name="value"`

Comment: I think this is the first question I encountered where the OP unknowingly had the answer within the question... when you're not sure how something works, your best bet is to search for it and read documentation or [examples](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-where/). A lot of knowledge is already out there, within a simple search's reach.

Comment: sometimes, good rubber-ducking requires one to read aloud your own question, before committing it on SO :)

Comment: mysql is a spoken language.  that clearly shows this question and that's why i like mysql so much

Comment: how to add where date >= (date field from a form in the same page)